# how to pick all links which has `href` or `onclick` use python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
for lnk in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile('.+')}):
for lnk in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'onclick': re.compile('.+')}):
```

how to pick all these  tag which has href not empty or has a onclick attr

Comment: What is wrong with the code you posted, more specific than "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

```
soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "a" and (tag.has_attr("onclick") or len(tag["href"]) > 0))
```

Comment: I think OP wants `or`, not `and`.

Comment: how to filter in tag <a>

Comment: Updated @Mario7